# How to determine which derived class a type is convertible to, if base class is known?

Tags: c++

Consider following code:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A{};

struct X
{    
    operator B() {return {};}
};

int main()
{
    A a = X{};
}
```

`A a = X{};` does work, and causes `X::operator B` to be invoked.

Is it possible to determine type `B` at compile-time, if I only know `X` and `A`?

In other words, is it possible to write a type trait `foo_t`, so that `foo_t<X, A>` = `B`?

Comment: In my first comment I'd misread the trait requirements. I've been thinking of a way to do this, but there's also the issue that there might exist some type `C` such that you could reasonably have `foo_t<X, A> = C`. And even if there weren't, I think this problem is unsolvable with the template system.

Comment: @CruzJean I also begin to think that it's impossible. About the ambiguity issue: I don't expect the trait to work if `X` is not convertible to `A`.

Comment: I was thinking we could do something with `std::is_assignable` or `std::is_constructible`, but those wouldn't be able to find some 3rd type that's used in the middle (like B is here). That's more so a logical programming question, which C++ doesn't support